# GcmTaskService: What's an "in-flight task" documentation mentions?

Tags: android, android-task

The documentation for `GcmNetworkManager::cancelTask` 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager"

says

> Cancel a task, specified by tag. Note that a cancel will have no
>   effect on an **in-flight task**.

What's an "in-flight" task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the GcmNetworkManager collects various requests and executes them batch-wise (in the intention to minimize the times, the network system is used, in order to save battery).

To my understanding, "in-flight" then means tasks, that are really already started, i.e. where the syncing is already in progress. So basically, you can only cancel tasks that have not yet started.